# Cisco Aironet 1200 Access Point Roaming

Tags: cisco, wifi, access-point

I have 5 Cisco 1200 Access point. 1 of them is running as WDS and 4 AP is using it.

I am using **Default Radio Channel: Least Congested Frequency**.

On the AP running WDS, I can see all 5 APs are registered by:

```
show wlccp wds ap
```

The problem is, in room1 my laptop (Dell laptop running Windows 7) connects to AP1, then I walk to room2, it does not roam to AP2. Same for room3's AP3. It connects to AP3 if the signal from AP1 is lost.

Is there anything I can do to configure the APs to roam?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get a controller such as a 2504 with 5 licenses. Controllers make it very easy to roam quickly between APs.

Have you enabled CCKM on the APs?
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/access_point/12.2_15_JA/configuration/guide/s15roamg.html#wp1051791

Comment: I tried enabling CCKM on the APs. But my dell laptop (Dell Wireless 1505 WLAN Mini-Card) can not connect to the SSID anymore.

Some background info:
5 APs are running same SSID with same VLAN to a switch. Users are authenticated against Windows NPS (RADIUS) server.